# Windows entry missing in grub after MXLinux update (Dual-Boot)

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub

I recently updated my MX21 to MX23 using this guide( https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/upgrading-from-mx-21-to-mx-23-without-reinstalling/ ), but now the Windows entry is missing in the Grub start up menu. I've tried tools like os-prober and update-grub but that doesn't work(altough os-prober detects windows). I can still boot into windows via BIOS(UEFI) but it would be nice to have it in grub again.

Here are some Output that might seem relevant:

```
$ sudo os-prober
/dev/nvme1n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi

$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/mx_linux/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-18-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,001C,0000,0001,0016,0017,0018,0019,001D,001B,001A
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* MX21
Boot0010  Setup
Boot0011  Boot Menu
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0016* USB CD
Boot0017* USB FDD
Boot0018* NVMe0
Boot0019* NVMe1
Boot001A  Other CD
Boot001B  Other HDD
Boot001C* USB HDD
Boot001D* PXE BOOT
Boot001E  Regulatory Information

$ sudo fdisk -l
Festplatte /dev/nvme1n1: 476,94 GiB, 512110190592 Bytes, 1000215216 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: SAMSUNG MZALQ512HALU-000L1              
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: gpt
Festplattenbezeichner: 64E694DB-94B8-4601-B569-E595B7292C23

Gerät             Anfang       Ende  Sektoren  Größe Typ
/dev/nvme1n1p1      2048     206847    204800   100M EFI-System
/dev/nvme1n1p2    206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserviert
/dev/nvme1n1p3    239616  502103419 501863804 239,3G Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/nvme1n1p5 999139328 1000212479   1073152   524M Windows-Wiederherstellungsumgebung
/dev/nvme1n1p6 502104064  851019775 348915712 166,4G Linux root (x86)

Partitionstabelleneinträge sind nicht in Festplatten-Reihenfolge.
```

Any help is appreciated!